# sftp chmod recursive

Tags: linux, sftp, chmod

I have logged into a server via sftp via terminal.

When I run the command

```
chmod -R 755 ./*
```

I get the error `You must supply a numeric argument to the chmod command.`.  How do I apply a recursive chmod 755 while in sftp?

Comment: yes - that's what i wrote in my question

Comment: `chmod 755 -R ./*` in this way?

Comment: @John: I edited my answer yesterday, I think I found what you were looking for, have a glance at it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to.  There's a good chance the chmod available to you via FTP or SFTP does not support the recursive option.  Commands available under FTP/SFTP are often somewhat crippled versions of what you'd have available locally under the shell.  If you're lucky, chmod may act recursively even without the `-R` option but if you're unlucky, you'll have to traverse the tree, chmod'ing each level one-at-a-time.

Comment: Or write a script that does it for you.

Comment: Sure, you can write a script, but the script has parse the result of the remote `ls` one level at a time and use that to create the list of subdirs, then keep recursing.  Not only is it doable, I've done it myself when I had to manage a remote FTP site.  But it's a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 4):

From `man sftp`:

> `chmod mode path`
>
> Change permissions of file path to mode.  **path may
>   contain glob(3) characters and may match multiple files.**

`man 7 glob` (`man 3 glob` references glob(7)) describes the *, ? and [] wildcard patterns we are familiar with when using `ls`. So you could use:

```
chmod 755 ./*
chmod 755 ./*/*
chmod 755 ./*/*/*
```

repeatedly until you have reached all files and get the error:

```
Couldn't setstat on "./*/*/*": No such file or directory
```

Before such a mass change, you could double-check in advance which directories would be affected with `lls` (from `man sftp`):

> `lls [ls-options [path]]`
>
> Display local directory listing of either path or current directory if
>   path is not specified.  **ls-options may contain any flags supported by
>   the local system's ls(1) command.**  path may contain glob(3) characters
>   and may match multiple files.

like this (specify an absolute path to `lls` to avoid surprises):

```
lls -Rla /path
```

You can also use `lls -Rla /path` to make sure your `chmod` worked as expected.

Comment: Multi-level wildcards may or may not be supported, depending on the server.  But if it works at all, you're right, this is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a server where the recursive did not seem to be supported as per Nicole's comment above. The wildcard chmod did work, but was timing out trying to run on the insane folder structure.

What did the trick for me in the end was actually Filezilla - although I couldn't recursively chmod via terminal, Filezilla was able to do it somehow via it's GUI.